# Java getting id from csv file to combo box

Tags: java, arrays, combobox, jcombobox

I am have a program were there are two forms one for the consultant and for the customer. On the first form the user will enter the consultant details and his ID will be saved in a csv file and this works fine.

```
Consultant cons_save = new Consultant();
    cons_save.setPersonfirstname(this.jTextField1.getText());
    cons_save.setPersonlastname(this.jTextField2.getText());
    cons_save.setPersonID(this.jTextField4.getText());
    this.jTextField1.setText("");
    this.jTextField2.setText("");
    this.jTextField3.setText("");

    cons_save.ConsultantID = cons_save.PersonID;

    cons_save.setConsultantID(this.jTextField4.getText());
    this.jTextField4.setText("");

    try
{
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("E:\\ryan_assignment_sit2\\ConsID\\consID.csv", true));

    writer.append(cons_save.ConsultantID);  
        writer.append(",");
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
catch(IOException e)
{
     e.printStackTrace();
} 

    cons_save.savecons();
```

After the id is saved the Id is called out from the csv to an array and this works fine as well.

```
       public CreateCustomer() {
    initComponents();

    ArrayList<String> ConsIDList = new ArrayList<String>();

    String csvFileToRead = "E:\\ryan_assignment_sit2\\ConsID\\consID.csv"; // Reads the CSV File.
    BufferedReader br = null; // Creates a buffer reader.
    String line = "";
    String splitBy = ","; // Reader Delimiter

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFileToRead)); // Buffer Reader with file name to read.
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { //While there is a line to read.
            reader = new Scanner(line);
            reader.useDelimiter(splitBy);

            while (reader.hasNext()) { // While there is a next value (token).
                ConsIDList.add(reader.next());
            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) { // Exception Handler if the File is not Found.
        exception.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException exception) { // Input/Output exception
        exception.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close(); // Close the Scanner.
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }



        Vector<String> vectorData = new Vector<String>(ConsIDList);

        DefaultComboBoxModel<String> comboBoxModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(vectorData);

        this.jComboBox1.setModel(comboBoxModel);



    }
}
```

The array is working fine but the combo box is not getting populated with the arraylist.

Comment: ComboBoxModel is an interface and you can't instantiate it. Use classes that implements it like FilterCombo box model.

Comment: Yes I edited the post, I noticed that just as I posted the question